# JavaScript for loop undefined

Tags: javascript

I wanted to make a couple of squares. When you press on one of them the square would disappear.

```js
var square = document.querySelectorAll(".square");

for (var i = 0; i < square.length; i++) {
  square[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    square.style.display = "none";
  })
}
```

```css
.square {
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
```

For some reason console says `"TypeError: square.style is undefined"`...

Comment: `square.style.display = "none";` must be `square[i].style.display = "none";` and `for (var i = 0; i < square.length; i++)` must be `for (let i = 0; i < square.length; i++)`

Comment: `this.style.display = "none";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Read the error message carefully: It says that `style` is undefined, not `square`.

`square` is the return value of `getElementsByClassName`: The collection of all the squares.

If you want to get the element that was clicked on, you need to use `this` or the `event.currentTarget`.

```js
var square = document.querySelectorAll(".square");

for (var i = 0; i < square.length; i++) {
  square[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    e.currentTarget.style.display = "none";
  })
}
```

```css
.square {
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
```

---

Warning: Div elements are not designed to be interactive. They won't appear in the tab order or be announced as interactive by screen readers. If you want something for the user to click on: Use a `<button>` instead.

Comment: *If you want to get the element that was clicked on, you need to use [...] `event.currentTarget`* `currentTarget` is not necessarily the *element that was clicked on*, it could also be the element that was clicked *in*. Your solution is predestined to be used as a delegate listener.